# get return type of methods at runtime

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to get the private methods of an apple framework (to eventually re-implement a couple of things), I managed to get the method name easily, but I can't get the return type at all.

code:

```
Method *methodList = class_copyMethodList(objc_getMetaClass("SenTestProbe"), &methodCount);
for (i=0; i<methodCount; i++) {
    NSString *methodName = NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(methodList[i]));
    char returnType[255];
    method_getReturnType(methodList[i],returnType , 255);
    struct objc_method_description *method = method_getDescription(methodList[i]);
    const char *encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(methodList[i]);
    NSLog(@"%s %s (%s) %@;",returnType,encoding,method->types,methodName);
}
```

output:

```
v v8@0:4 (v8@0:4) load;
v v8@0:4 (v8@0:4) load;
v v8@0:4 (v8@0:4) initialize;
c c8@0:4 (c8@0:4) isTesting;
c c8@0:4 (c8@0:4) isProcessActingAsTestRig;
@ @8@0:4 (@8@0:4) testScope;
c c8@0:4 (c8@0:4) isLoadedFromApplication;
c c8@0:4 (c8@0:4) isLoadedFromTool;
@ @12@0:4@8 (@12@0:4@8) testCaseNamesForScopeNames:;
@ @8@0:4 (@8@0:4) testedBundlePath;
c c8@0:4 (c8@0:4) isInverseTestScope;
@ @16@0:4@8c12 (@16@0:4@8c12) multiTestSuiteForScope:inverse:;
v v12@0:4@8 (v12@0:4@8) runTests:;
@ @8@0:4 (@8@0:4) specifiedTestSuite;
v v16@0:4@8@12 (v16@0:4@8@12) runTestsAtUnitPath:scope:;
```

It seems that `typeEncoding` and the `method->types` returns the same I `method_getReturnType` returns only the the first character.

Can anyone help me with this please, I need to find the Arguments, the Arguments Types, and the return types, for all the methods.

Any help with be appreciated.

**Update:**

It seems that I was missed the table with type [encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) which would allow to get the matching types. Thanks @RichardJ.RossIII for your reply.

If anyone reads this post [RunTimeBrowser](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser/) link given by @WDUK to get private headers of any framework does this perfectly without any hassle (specially the mac version). It also provides with a good learning tool around the runtime framework.

I hope this helps and thanks everyone for your help.

This link provides with a https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Comment: Look at the docs for [type encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, Private Framework headers (in readable format) can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Comment: @WDUK i am not trying to reinvent the wheel, but I am modifying OCUnit, and the only source code i found is from 2005, besides that this has been a good thing to learn, but thank you for the link, I have bookmarked it, for future reference.

Comment: @RicardoDuarte Fair enough. In that case, the source for generating those files can be found at https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser/. You can have a look at the implementation to see how they interpret the information.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII thank you, It looks like i missed that table in that page, is there a quick way to decode, something that does the opposite of @encode?

Comment: @WDUK that seems to be it:D thank you.I am bookmarking it, and checking it out.Thanks:D

Comment: The return type for the method _is_ the first character (except in the case of a struct return) of the encoding string. You're getting the correct values from these functions. It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i didn't knew that, I was expecting a string with the encoding name, RichardJ.RossIII first reply clarified the pieces i was missing. Should have read the whole thing regarding runtime methods in the apple docs, my bad.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're expecting the class name? That's not preserved in the encoding string, because it's irrelevant to what the encoding is used for. Any object is `@`.

Comment: Yes i realize that, i kinda wanted a lazy way out, while learning some bits. But WDUK second post points at an excellent link, and with the missing information that RichardJ.RossIII gave me i should be able to figure it out (i hope).

Comment: @RicardoDuarte you can 'decode' it by using `NSGetSizeAndAlignment`, although it won't give you any names.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just assign the return to an `id`, then print its class?

you can start shaping it from there.

Comment: i could but then i would still have to consult the type encodings table to get argument types.

Comment: Didn't know you needed arguments. But I do think that answers that question. You can't expect something as unorthodox as scooping apples code to be a painless job, you can always write a script to scrap that for you btw. Anyway I'm sorry I couldn't help with more. Good luck :)